# How can I connect an L298 H-bridge motor driver using Pi-Face

Tags: gpio

I have a [Pi-Face](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-52857?CMP=KNC-EU-RPI-ACC-PIFACE) which I have successfully used to switch on and off some LED's but I'm a bit stuck on taking the next step - to drive a [robot chassis](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Dual-H-Bridge-DC-Stepper-Motor-Drive-Controller-Board-Module-Arduino-L298N-236-/140743762410?nma=true&si=7oqjJOwgRllk7qVYSglMC1xFD0A%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557).

I purchased [one of these](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Dual-H-Bridge-DC-Stepper-Motor-Drive-Controller-Board-Module-Arduino-L298N-236-/140743762410?nma=true&si=7oqjJOwgRllk7qVYSglMC1xFD0A%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557) l298 motor drivers but I'm completely stuck on how to connect up the pi faces open collector outputs to the l298.

From searching about on the net it appears that it definitely possible but I just cant figure it out.

This question is tagged gpio but it relates specifically to the pi face board as there is no pi face tag yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to have a (pullup) resistor from the output to +5 of the driver board.

The value of the resistor isn't too important. Something like 1k is probably a good starting point.